# Fetching child data via pagination

Tags: java, hibernate, pagination

My User class contains user posts via OneToMany relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<Post> post;

    public Set<Post> getPost() {
        return post;
    }
```

Post class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
```

It also contains several other child classes with other relationships. 
Say a particular loggedIn user contains `n` posts.
I need to fetch the posts `getPost()` via pagination.

The [examples](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-pagination) I see on web take the class name as a parameter `[code below]`. If I provide the User class as a parameter It will paginate the users from the database I believe. I only need to paginate results of `getPost()` method only for the particular loggedIn user.

From the example

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
criteria.setFirstResult(0);
criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
List<Foo> firstPage = criteria.list();
```

Can anyone guide me how do I do that?

Comment: `Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Post.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(userIdProperty, userId));
criteria.setFirstResult(offsetFromPage);
criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
List<Post> firstPage = criteria.list();`

Comment: @Pawel When I pass the username or his id to criteria.add("userId",userIdValue); I get an error The method add(Criterion) in the type Criteria is not applicable for the arguments (String, Integer) or (String, String)

Comment: Add restriction in `criteria.add` as i wrote in comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write query for Post entities and use current user as parameter in this query.